# Angular uigrid export selected produces empty csv

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a uigrid that contains a large number of column definitions that aren't initially filled with data because the data set would be too large. Instead, I get the requested column data when the column visibility changes.

This causes an issue with the built in csv exporter. When someone chooses to "Export all data as csv" they get numerous empty columns.

So I've made my own implementation as follows:

```
   $interval( function() {
      gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{
        title: 'Export All to CSV',
        order: 1,
        action: function ($event) {
          var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
          $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, myElement );
        }
      }]);
      gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{
        title: 'Export Selected to CSV',
        order: 2,
        action: function ($event) {
          if(gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount > 0){
            var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
            $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, myElement );
          }
        }
      }]);
      gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{
        title: 'Export Visible to CSV',
        order: 3,
        action: function ($event) {
          var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
          $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, myElement );
        }
      }]);
    }, 0, 1);
```

Export All to CSV and Export Visible to CSV work as expected, but Export Selected just creates an CSV file with only headers, no data.

I know the grid is aware of the selection, the following returns the elements that are selected to the console:

```
       gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{
        title: 'Export Selected to CSV',
        order: 2,
        action: function ($event) {
          if(gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount > 0){
            var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
            $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, myElement );
            console.log(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows());
            gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().forEach(function (entry) {
              console.log(entry);
              for (var e in entry){
                console.log(entry[e]);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }]);
```

I suppose I could use the data returned by getSelectedRows to make my own CSV, but I'd rather not. Is uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED broken?

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it using the public API and some of my own hacking:

```
                    gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{
                    title: 'Export Selected to CSV',
                    order: 2,
                    action: function ($event) {
                        if(gridApi.grid.selection.selectedCount > 0){
                            var uiExporter = uiGridExporterService;
                            var grid = $scope.gridApi.grid;
                            uiExporter.loadAllDataIfNeeded(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE).then(function() {
                                var exportColumnHeaders = uiExporter.getColumnHeaders(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
                                var selectionData = [];
                                gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().forEach(function (entry) {
                                    var innerData = [];
                                    for (var e in entry){
                                        if (e !== '$$hashKey') {
                                            var selectObj = {value:entry[e]};
                                            innerData.push(selectObj);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    selectionData.push(innerData);
                                });
                                var csvContent = uiExporter.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, selectionData, grid.options.exporterCsvColumnSeparator);
                                uiExporter.downloadFile($scope.gridOptions.exporterCsvFilename, csvContent, grid.options.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]);
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Comment: Way too complicated. You can just run `gridApi.exporter.csvExport(uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL)` on the action.